# Need help on update and delete sqlite on the tableview

Tags: xcode, sqlite, ios6

I'm a beginner on xcode and I have very little knowledge about it. Here is my code. I'm doing a simple account management program for iOS 6.0. I need to select the row from where i'm going to edit/delete my data from the table view and then be able to update/delete it. I don't know how to code those and I need help from experienced programmers.
My project: http://www.mediafire.com/?95l8pwzu3c62ts0

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface FlipsideViewController ()

@end
@implementation FlipsideViewController

@synthesize entries;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.label.text=self.strUsername;
    entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self openDB];
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM SUMMARY8 WHERE theuser = '%s'",[self.label.text UTF8String]];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare(account, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW){
            char *field1=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0 );
            NSString *field1Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field1];

        char *field2=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1 );
          NSString *field2Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field2];

            char *field3=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2 );
            NSString *field3Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field3];

            char *field4=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3 );
            NSString *field4Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field4];

            NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ - %@", field1Str,field3Str,field4Str];
            [entries addObject:str];
        }
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(NSString *) filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"account.sql"];
}
-(void) openDB
{
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &account) !=SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(account);
        NSAssert(0,@"Database failed to open");

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"database opened");
    }
}

- (IBAction)addaccount:(id)sender {
    MainViewController *FVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
    FVC.strUsername=self.strUsername;

    [self presentViewController:FVC animated:YES completion:nil];
   // FVC.label.text=self.label.text;
}

- (IBAction)btnEdit:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)btnDelete:(id)sender {
    [self tableView:<#(UITableView *)#> cellForRowAtIndexPath:<#(NSIndexPath *)#>];
}

#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    NSString *myTitle = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Name - Username - Password"];
    return myTitle;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      NSLog(@"%d", [entries count]);
    return [entries count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{//NSLog(@"test");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *selectedRow = [entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM SUMMARY8 WHERE name = '%@'",selectedRow];

    char *err;
    if (sqlite3_exec(account, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err)!=SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(account);
        NSAssert(0, @"Could not delete row");

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"row deleted");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" message:@"Account was deleted successfully!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

@end
```

is this correct? sorry I absolutely have no background on Xcode. So sorry for the bother..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete use this:

Example:`strUpdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM SUMMARY8 WHERE theuser = '%s'",[self.label.text UTF8String]];`

Update use this:

Example(updating the status):`strQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE SUMMARY8 SET STATUS='1' WHERE theuser = '%s'",[self.label.text UTF8String]];`

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
use this method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

Example: NSString *selectedRow = [entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

This method basically shows the data for that row of table. manipulate with that data. Given examples.. Tweak it according to your situation...

EDIT 2:

For example:

```
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] init];
[self tableView:table didSelectRowAtIndexPath:index];
```

where index is your item number.

Comment: that answered one my problems on what the sql statement should be. Thank you for that. but I also need to know how to get the data on the selected row on the table. btw, here is my project http://www.mediafire.com/?95l8pwzu3c62ts0

Comment: hope this helps... give it a try.. got more questions, ask.. more than happy to help..

Comment: I've added the delete and select code you told me but I don't know if that's the right place to put it in...lol..problem is I dont know how to call the (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ so that I could call the statement on my btnDelete button to delete a selected row from a table...